# Can I run stanza NER without downloading the language modules?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-stanza

I need to run stanza ner in a platform without any access to external network. The code `stanza.download('en')` fails. Running without the download function, gives me an exception

`Exception: Resources file not found at: \home\stanza_resources\resources.json. Try to download the model again`

Is there a way to download and cache all the required modules in a resource directory and point this directory to stanza pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like both download and the Pipeline class take an argument for directory `dir`

So the below code works

`stanza.download('en', dir='resources/', processors={ner_processor: package})`

`nlp_pipeline = stanza.Pipeline('en', dir='resources/', processors={ner_processor: package})`